# iOS: event is not saved. Need help debug

Tags: ios, xcode

The following is the full code for addEvent action.

```
- (IBAction)addEventBtnPressed:(id)sender
{
    EKEvent *myEvent = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore:self.eventStore];
    myEvent.title = self.eventTitle.text;
    myEvent.startDate = self.eventStartDate;
    myEvent.endDate = self.eventEndDate;
    myEvent.allDay = NO;

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MMMM dd hh:mma"];
    NSString *startTestDate = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:self.eventStartDate];
    NSString *endTestDate = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:self.eventEndDate];
    NSLog(@"Test title String:%@", myEvent.title);
    NSLog(@"Test Start Date String:%@", startTestDate);
    NSLog(@"Test Start Date String:%@", endTestDate);

    [myEvent setCalendar:[self.eventStore defaultCalendarForNewEvents]];
    NSError *err;

    [self.eventStore saveEvent:myEvent span:EKSpanThisEvent error:&err];

    if (err == noErr) {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                              initWithTitle:@"Event Created"
                              message:@"Yay!?"
                              delegate:nil
                              cancelButtonTitle:@"Okay"
                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
    }
}
```

The logs:

```
2014-10-28 04:44:18.881 Calendar[2668:1628432] Test title String:jtjtjtjrj
2014-10-28 04:44:18.882 Calendar[2668:1628432] Test Start Date String:October 30 12:00AM
2014-10-28 04:44:18.882 Calendar[2668:1628432] Test Start Date String:October 30 01:00AM
```

It seems to me there's really nothing wrong with the code, and I am not sure why the event is not saved when I check in the regular calendar. After hours of trying, I am stumped. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE:**

I was calling setDateLabels() method on viewDidLoad, and once I stopped calling this method events were being added correctly again. I am confused why this would have any effect though. The code looks like this:

```
- (void)setDateLables:(NSDate*)firstSelectedDate
{
    [self.datePicker setDate:firstSelectedDate];
    NSDate *startDate = firstSelectedDate;
    NSTimeInterval anHourAfter = 1 * 60 * 60;
    NSDate *endDate = [startDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:anHourAfter];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MMMM dd hh:mma"];
    self.eventStartDate = startDate;
    self.eventEndDate = endDate;
    self.startDateLabel.text = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:startDate];
    self.endDateLabel.text = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:endDate];
}
```

I am suspecting `NSDate *endDate = [startDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:anHourAfter];` has some unexpected behavior. Any help will be appreciated!

**I pinned it down to one line of code:**
I can add events successfully as long as I get rid of `[self.datePicker setDate:firstSelectedDate];`. I added this line to start the datepicker on the selected date and it was working successfully visually, but it prevented events from being added. What might be a possible reason behind this?

Comment: [startDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:anHourAfter]; works fine. Have you stepped through the code in the debugger looking at the various variables? You also need to post the source of your event store.

Comment: @RogerNolan I updated the code again. Dynamically setting the starting date for the datepicker was the problem but I am not sure why it would prevent events from being added. Do you have an idea?

Comment: Need to see saveEvent::

Comment: Here's the reference to saveEvent: https://developer.apple.com/LIBRARY/ios/documentation/EventKit/Reference/EKEventStoreClassRef/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/EKEventStore/saveEvent:span:error:

Comment: Ah, apple code :-) so my answer is right then. check your value of noErr. It's not needed and you should check !err.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely `err` is not equal to `noErr`. What is noErr set to?

Anyway, without knowing the implementation of saveEvent, it should leave err untouched if there is no error so you want to check:

```
if (!err) {
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                          initWithTitle:@"Event Created"
                          message:@"Yay!?"
                          delegate:nil
                          cancelButtonTitle:@"Okay"
                          otherButtonTitles:nil];
```